# How to select items from listview? I correctly get the selected value

Tags: android, listview

I get the position from selected items but not display when i click my items in listview. I attached code below and attached screenshot:

```
      listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            list_pos=position;

            for (int i = 0; i < itemlist.size(); i++) {
                if (i == position) {
                    System.out.println("**********venki*******hai*");
                    itemlist.get(i).setSelect_show("selected");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("**********venki*******notslected*");
                    itemlist.get(i).setSelect_show("not selected");
                }
            }

             if (itemlist.get(position).getRatingId().equalsIgnoreCase("13")){
                // showreviewPopup();
                 Et_comment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

             }else{
                 Et_comment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             }


        }
    });
}
```

This is my adapter class:

```
    if(data.get(position).getSelect_show().equalsIgnoreCase("selected")){



        holder.Im_sel_option.setImageResource(R.drawable.card_selected);

    }else {

        holder.Im_sel_option.setImageResource(R.drawable.card_unselect);

    }
```

[image]

Comment: `I get the position from selected items but not display when I click my items in the listview.` what do you mean by that? If you're talking about item view then your are `view` in your onItemClickListener.

Comment: How to show which item I select in that listview?

Comment: try adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() just after you call setSelect_show() and see if that works

Comment: @vlatkozelka Thank you so much. Its working.